# Stop a running application tomcat server

Tags: tomcat

I have a problem that i hope you can help me with.

Sometimes my applications get some errors and keeps on running on the server until i manually stops the server and make a restart.

Because i have more jobs running on the server i would like to just stop this specific job without having to restart the whole server.

I thought i solved the problem when ive found out that you can stop applications in tomcat manager but when i tried to stop the application after i already started my webservice job nothing havent. When i checked the server status the job was still running..

So my question is if there is some way to quit a job that is already started without having to shutdown the whole server?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You could implement your job so that it periodically checks if it's allowed to continue. This is best practice for long-running jobs anyway. If that's in place, you can easily provide a UI for the feature - be it on application restart or individual per job.